# Get Value via Cells() using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I am trying to use the Value of column 'X' and a specific row.

When I click on my button a macro is called with the Column and the row.
I double checked this with: id = 17 and id2 = 24.

```vb
Private Function GetID(ByVal id As String, ByVal id2 As String) As String
    MsgBox ("row: " & id & " - column: " & id2)
End Function
```

When I try to use the value of the specific cell, I got an error 1004:

```vb
MsgBox ("row: " & id & " - column: " & id2 & " - Value: " & CStr(Cells(id, id2).Value))
```

The problem seems to be `Cells(id, id2)`. If I put in 24 instead of id2 it works.

```vb
MsgBox ("row: " & id & " - column: " & id2 & " - Value: " & CStr(Cells(id, 24).Value))
```

Why is it not working with id2 as a parameter?

Comment: Did you try to convert the `id2` to a numeric type? For example `CInt(id2)`. As I can see the `id2` is of `String` type, whereas the `Cells` property expects a numeric type.

Comment: `Cells` will accept either a column letter, or a column number, but it won't accept a number passed as a `String` data type. Because the row has to be a number, it will convert implicitly from a string.

Comment: I checked that after converting the `id2` to `Integer`, it works: `?Cells(id, CInt(id2)).Value`.

Comment: Thanks @TomaszPaluch I had to convert the id2 into int.

Comment: Why are you declaring the parameters as `String` in the first place? The row number should be a `Long` and the column a `Variant`.

Answer (score 1):

I had to convert the value into an INT value.
This is working:

```
Dim id2Convert
id2Convert = CInt(id2)
MsgBox ("row: " & id & " - column: " & id2 & " - Value: " & CStr(Cells(id, id2Convert).Value))
```